# Interface vs Class method parameter ambiguity

Tags: c#, methods, interface, ambiguous

I am certain that I simply do not know the name for what I am trying to do, otherwise my googling would be more successful.  I currently only find results pertaining to interfaces with same named methods.

I have a few classes that inherit from a common base class and some implement an interface.  I have methods accepting the base class or the interface as a parameter.  I cannot compile since this causes ambiguity with the error

> the call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: DoThings(IQueryable<A>) and DoThings(IQueryable<B>)` on the call in ConcreteExecutionClass.

Furthermore, generics won't work because type constraints on generics do not make a unique method signature.

Is there a way (or an acceptable pattern) to force the execution to a specific method based on parameter types?

```
public abstract class A {
    // some properties
}

public class ConcreteA : A {
    // full implementation
}

public interface B {
    // a property
}

public class ConcreteAB : A, B {
    // full implementation
}

public abstract class ExecutionClass {
    public IQueryable<A> DoThings(IQueryable<A> content){
        return A.method().AsQueryable();
    }

    public IQueryable<B> DoThings(IQueryable<B> content){
        return B.interfaceRequiredMethod().method().AsQueryable();
    }
}

public class ConcreteExecutionClass : ExecutionClass {
    public void Program(){
        var objectList = new List<ConcreteAB>{/*....*/};
        DoThings(objectList);
    }
}
```

Each of the concrete classes has a class managing linq queries on lists of objects, which each call `DoThings()`.  The goal is to keep the actual implementation of `DoThings()` transparent to the concrete classes.

I have attempted covariance in the interface, however have been unable to avoid inheriting A which forces down the first code path.

The code above is a simplification of the actual implementation.  There are about 10 classes deriving solely from `A` and 4 deriving from `A` and `B`.

Comment: Which method do you expect to be called for `ConcreteAB`? And why?

Comment: You may refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42078610/c-sharp-generic-method-resolution-fails-with-an-ambiguous-call-error/42078735#42078735

Comment: @Ryu that post is why I said that generics don't work

Comment: @Rob I want the DoThings(B) to be called. I understand why it is ambiguous and am looking for a solution. I am thinking about trying to cast ConcreteAB to B when it is passed as a parameter, however this doesn't make it transparent to the ConcreteExecution class

Comment: Then your only option is to have a third overload; C. Where C is an abstract class subclassing A and implementing B. Though your design overwhelmingly seems to be a bad idea.

Comment: I you want DoThings(B) to be called then you could type cast it , no problem at all. Since there is a ambiguity you can certainly help run time to solve this using type casting.

Comment: I'm reading this using my cellphone so perhaps I'm missing something critical here, but it seems to me like an explicit interface implementation should solve this problem.

Comment: @ZoharPeled no, it is not an interface implementation problem, it is an overload resolution problem

Comment: Yeah, after another read on my computer I understand your problem better. Upvoted your asnwer, though it seems a bit more like a workaround then a solution :-)

Comment: @ZoharPeled unfortunately I am stuck with this implementation.  Trying to add functionality to an api where I don't have access to all the controllers but I do have access to an abstract controller they all inherit from.

Answer (score 0):

I simply created an abstract hierarchy where abstract A is the base and there are 2 abstract classes inheriting from it.